# Using Mysql in iOs App

Tags: mysql, ios, web

My friend already has his own working web-site (selling some stuff). We have an idea to create the **iOs app** for the site to attract more people(for me - to gain some badly needed experience).

The **UI** is going to be simple, and there won't as many problems, as using the web-site's data. We need the app to have some data locally, so that people, who do not have an internet access, were able to use the app.

But, of course, we want the information in the app to be up-to-date, so I need to use **MySQL** data somehow (I mean, that if the person has an internet access, the app can use it and download some data, If not - the app must contain some data to show). To be honest, I want the app to be really good, so I have a question: **What combination is better to use???**

1. To use core data, create a data model(it is huge and it's difficult to reproduce it, a lot of classes to create). I can do it, but how to update the data then? =) Have no idea.
2. To create a **sqlite** database, then use something like **php** code to insert get and encode the data into **json**, then parse it.
3. Maybe I should connect to **MySQL** directly from the app and use it's data, because it's impossible to have same data locally?
4. Or just to parse it, using **json** or **xml**?

Please, help me guys, I need my app to be cool and robust, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe you can tell the better way to solve such a problem??

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'll have to build a similar database inside your application using SQLite and import data from MySQL through some kind of API bridge. A simple way to do this data interchange is via JSON that encodes the record's attributes. XML is also a possible transport mechanism but tends to have more overhead and ends up being trickier to use. What you'll be sending back and forth is generally sets of key-value pairs, not entire documents.

Stick to Core Data unless you have an exceptionally good reason to use something else. Finding it irritating or different is not a good reason. It can be a bit tricky to get the hang of at first, but in practice it tends to be mostly unobtrusive if used correctly.

Unless you're writing something that's expressly a MySQL client, **never** connect directly to MySQL in an iOS application. Period. Don't even think about doing this. Not only is it impossible to secure effectively, but iOS networking is expected to be extremely unreliable, slow, and often unavailable entirely. Your application must be able to make use of limited bandwidth, deal with very high latency, and break up operations into small transactions that are likely to succeed instead of one long-running operation that is bound to fail.

How do you sync data between your database and your client? That depends on what web stack you're going to be using. You have a lot of options here, but at the very least you should prototype in something like Ruby on Rails, Django, or NodeJS. PHP is viable, but without a database framework will quickly become very messy.