# iOS remote MySQL database, technology recommendation

Tags: java, python, mysql, ios, ruby

There is web application, journalism related, that uses MySQL databases and presents a web based interface to users.

I want to build a iOS app that does a mobile interface as well. The UI is pretty easy and I have experience with that.

The problem is with the database, which I have no experience with.
I will be learning about databases and probably take the Coursera course on it. I am not asking you to teach me that. I just wanna know which technologies I should invest my time in over the next couple months.

My understanding so far is that the app should not talk to the database directly,
but rather there should be some one on the server talking to the database on behalf of the App.

This is the question and the part I want to understand clearly, so correct me if I am wrong.

I will have to write some sort of a unix program that runs on the server and talks to the db and then communicates back to app? how? using a web view? Using unix sockets to talk to the app? ssh? Which one is cool with Apple?

My preference for writing something like that on the server would be: python(have experience), java(have experience), and maybe ruby(no experience). I'd prefer to avoid scripting languages.

Are they ok? Which one is best suited? Also is this middle dude going to have to be on the same server that has the database or can be another machine on the internet(i'd prefer this, so i can put it on my own VPS and not have to screw up with the server machine)

Comment: In the future, please phrase your questions in the best English you can muster. This isn't a message board or an IM conversation.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595343/using-mysql-in-ios-app/14595417) from tonight, but you're coming at it from a different angle.

In general terms, an iOS application that needs to be able to run in offline mode will need to have its own database. This means creating Core Data models to store all of the data required by the application. Internally this is stored in a SQLite database.

If you want to make an application that's online-only, it's somewhat easier since you won't need to worry about the Core Data part and can instead focus on building your service API. If you're familiar with Python then your best bet is [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to provide that layer. You'll need to implement a number of endpoints that can receive requests, translate that into the appropriate database calls, then render the result in a machine readable format.

Scripting languages are what power most back-ends even for massive scale systems. In most cases the database will be the bottleneck and not the language used to interface with it. Even Twitter stuck with Ruby until they hit tens of millions of active users, so unless you're at that level, don't worry about it.

For most applications, using HTTP as your transport mechanism and [JSON](http://json.org/) as your encoding method is the way to go. It's very simple to construct, easy to consume, and fairly easy to read. There are probably a number of ways you might go about reading and writing this, but that's another question.

For small-scale applications where the number of users is measured in the hundreds then you can host the application and database on the same server. Even a modest VPS with 512MB of memory might do the job, though for heavier loads you might want to invest in a 1GB instance. It really depends on how often people are accessing your application and what the peak loads are like.

Comment: +1 for JSON/HTTP. If you don't want to learn Django, a web microframework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) might be suitable, perhaps used with SQLite or [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for SQL, or [MongoDB](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) if you'd like to try NoSQL.